# Split function in angualrjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

My output in js is {{msg}} not the content I wanted. How do I fix this? And, I can't write the split function properly. I want to count the number of string in the array used by split function. But, I don't know how to count?
Could you please answer me?
Here's the link: https://github.com/YangDeCheng12/angularjsmodule1_soln
Thank you.
I give the link because I can't pose my photo of code although photos are in my device.

Comment: Write your split function out here so we can see what isn't working. Please explain what isn't working as expected, the desired output, any errors, basically anything that can help us help you. We cannot currently see anything at all so cannot help here yet.

Comment: `input.split(/\s+/).count` where are you stuck? What is failing?

Comment: `My output is not the content I wanted. How do I fix this?` Seriously? Well, I'd say that the fix is to get the content you want :/

Answer (score 0):

I saw your code from github, I think you don't need the below code from checking function.

```
var total = input.split(" ");
            if (total.length < 4)
            {
                message = "Enjoy!";
            }
            else if (total.length = 0)
            {
                message = "Please enter data first";
            }
            else
            {
                message = "Too much!";
            }
```

**UPDATED**

I have checked your code again, seems like your app module is not initialized and hence your controller is not created. The app is not started yet, simply.

Comment: I got it, thank you
I have wrong spelling in the app module.

Comment: This is why your app module is not initialized. Great !!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are using the wrong `operator`for comparison, instead of `==` you are using the assignement operator `=` in :

```
else if (total.length = 0){
```

Your code should be like this:

```
var input = $scope.name;
var message ="";
var total = input.split(" ");
if (total.length < 4){
    message = "Enjoy!";
}else if (total.length == 0){
    message = "Please enter data first";
}else{
    message = "Too much!";
}
```